# GitHub GraphQL query not returning last commit

Tags: github, graphql

Everywhere I read, I see I can get the latest commit for a GitHub repository using this GraphQL query:

```
{
repository(owner: "petermorlion", name: "RedStar.Amounts") {
    defaultBranchRef {
      name
      target {
        ... on Commit {
          history(first: 1) {
            edges {
              node {
                committedDate
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And this works. For this repository. As you can see (at the time I'm writing this), both the [GraphQL explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/) and [the GitHub UI](https://github.com/petermorlion/RedStar.Amounts/commits/master) say 7th May is the latest commit:

[image: GitHub UI results]

[image: GitHub GraphQL results]

However, if I run this on another repository, I'm getting the first commit. Change the owner to `ystk` and the repository name to `debian-libidn`. GraphQL tells me the latest commit is 13th October 2009:

[image: GitHub GraphQL wrong results]

But [the GitHub UI](https://github.com/ystk/debian-libidn/commits/master) shows it is in fact 13th May 2011:

[image: GitHub UI correct results]

Is my query wrong? Should I be adding an `orderby` somewhere (I saw that it can't be added to `history`)?

Comment: have you tried adding orderby create date maybe like
orderBy: {field: CREATED_AT, direction: ASC}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The GraphQL query is actually right.

What has gone wrong there is the dating of the apparently older commit, which although is authored in 2009 it is indeed more recent than the 2011 one. By newer here we refer to being pushed at a later point than the other one. This means the timestamp of the commit was amended, which was possibly caused by a misconfiguration of the author's clock at the time.

The main page will always show the most recently pushed commit, which for [debian-libidn](https://github.com/ystk/debian-libidn), for example, it shows the 2009-dated one.

To detail further, there are three timestamp-related properties of `Commit` that you could retrieve:

- `committedDate`: the date at which point the commit was created locally. Updated when a commit was changed and affected by the author's clock
- `authoredDate`: by default same as `committedDate`, can be changed with the `--date` optional parameter when committing changes, also affected by the author's clock
- `pushedDate`: the date when the commit was pushed to the repository, according to the server's time (in this case GitHub's)

From the above, it seems you would prefer to use `pushedDate` instead, as that will give the real order of commits as they were pushed to the repo.

Comment: For a reproducible demo you may look at the repository I created for this purpose: author `SiavasFiroozbakht` and repo `TestRepo`. _New commit_ is shown as older though it was pushed after the _Initial commit_

Comment: Interesting. Searching a bit further, I tried replacing the commit block in my query with `... on Commit {
          committedDate
        }` Would that give me the lastest commit? It seems to.

Comment: @Peter I have elaborated on these timestamp-related fields of `Commit`. You could use `pushedDate` to get the actual date of when the commit was pushed. Note changing or adding fields in the query does not actually apply any filter by them. `history` [will give the same order as `git log`](https://developer.github.com/v4/object/commit/) apparently